# jquery hover menu

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery hover to display a submenu(id="submenu1") when hovering on the menu link(class="menu1").

I have used this code:

```
sp = $('img[class="menu1"]');
pn = $('#submenu1');   
sp.hover(function(){
  pn.show();
},
function(){
  setTimeout(function(){pn.hide();}, 500);
});

pn.hover(function(){
  pn.show();
},
function(){
   pn.hide();
});
```

The thing is, I want the sub menu to stay in case the user is hovering on it. 
Sometimes it works, sometimes no.. 
I have seen a few examples, none of them worked for me..

**Edit:**

The submenu **is not in the menu hierarchy** (it's absolutely positioned)

```
<!--menu btn to hover above:-->
<img src="menu.gif" alt="menu" />

<!--completly unrelated submenu:-->
<div id="submenu" >
...
</div>
```

Comment: It's all related to how your HTML is setup. Could you post the HTML for your menu and submenu. The submenu needs to be inside the menu item or else the hover-out will be executed.

Comment: I have been able to do such things with pure CSS. Have you tried that, or is it inapplicable?

Comment: Also, you can do $('img.menu1') instead of $('img[class="menu1"]')

Comment: Also, won't the settimeout keep executing until you clear it?

Comment: Check this fiddle I made. It can be as simple as this. http://jsfiddle.net/pr982/

Comment: the submenu is not in the menu hirechy, it's absolute position.

Comment: Is it the effect you are looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/QDug3/

Comment: hi @CharlesJourdan, thanks for the reply. It doesn't hide the submenu on mouseout of the sp. meaning, I have a few menu buttons, and sometimes you want to hover on them, without going on the submenu-> in this case the submenu won't disappear.

Comment: Can you provide an html with more details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code can help you.

**JS :**

```
$("img[id^='menu']").hover(function(){
  $("div[id^='submenu']").hide();
  $("#sub" + $(this).attr("id")).show();
},
function(){
    var it = this;

    setTimeout(function(){
      var submenu = $("#sub" + $(it).attr("id"));

      if(submenu.length > 0 && !submenu.is(":hover")){
        submenu.hide();
      }
    }, 200);
});

$("div[id^='submenu']").hover(function(){
},
function(){
  $(this).hide();
});

$("div[id^='submenu']").hide();
```

**HTML :**

```
<!--menu btn to hover above:-->
<img src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico" alt="menu1" id="menu1" height="30"/>
<img src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico" alt="menu1" id="menu2" height="30"/>
<img src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico" alt="menu1" id="menu3" height="30"/>
<img src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico" alt="menu1" id="menu4" height="30"/>


<!--completly unrelated submenu:-->
<div id="submenu3" >
This is a submenu3
</div>

<div id="submenu2" >
This is a submenu2
</div>

<div id="submenu4" >
This is a submenu4
</div>
```

With this code, you can find little bugs sometimes. The problem comes to setTimeout. If you are too slow the submenu is hidden. The difficulty comes from the DOM organization but you assume it.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/QDug3/6/) there is a jsfiddle to test the code.

Comment: thanks.. I did something a bit different but I can see that your code will work too..